# XSLT 1.0 trying to implement java code inside, but always ends with error

Tags: java, xslt, xalan

I just joined to project where they still use old XSLT 1.0/1.1 for documents print.
I gotta write some more logic, so i did some research about xalan.java/js, but i don't know why i cannot implement java code straight into mine xsl file, it drops error always. I spend on research whole day and i had to ask here.

My question is, is it even possible to print out function value like in example below?

**I notice import of java builded funcs works well**

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <fo:block>
       test over there:
          <xsl:call-template name="currentTime"/>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>     

<xsl:template name="currentTime" xmlns:java="http://xml.apache.org/xslt/java">
    <xsl:value-of select="java:java.util.Date.new()"/>
</xsl:template>
```

**But when i try to call java with xalan it cracks**

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <fo:block>
       java test over there:
          <xsl:call-template name="currentTime"/>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>     

<xsl:template name="currentTime" xmlns:java="http://xml.apache.org/xslt/java" xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xalan" xmlns:counter="MyCounter" extension-element-prefixes="counter">

     <xalan:component prefix="counter" functions="response">
        <xalan:script lang="java">

          public String response(name) {
            return "" + (name);
          }

        </xalan:script>
     </xalan:component>

    <xsl:value-of select="counter:response('hello')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think xalan:script only works with "scripting" languages like Javascript, not with Java. For Java you need to dynamically load compiled code from the classpath.

Comment: @MichaelKay You're right i believe. I'll try to figure it out classpath way :)